# Playwright wait on custom events

Tags: python, dom-events, playwright, webautomation, playwright-python

I am using Playwright in Python, and I want to inject javascript into a page that watches DOM mutations and fires custom events, and catch those events in Python.

This is an example python script:

```py
page.evaluate("//js code that essentially dispatches new CustomEvent('newPosts')")
page.on("newPosts", handle_posts)
```

So far, nothing happens on Python side, as if events do not exist.

If I manually check browser console, I can see events firing just fine on browser side (which I'm catching with `document.addEventListener('newPosts', fn)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this:

1. Register a listener with [expose_function](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-expose-function).
2. Use `evaluate` to register a listener to `newPosts`. A Listener on the browser side.
3. Inside that listener call the function you exposed on 1.