# How to validate if a custom event was triggered in Playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I have a scenario where in after clicking a certain element, a custom event should be triggered. The `waitForEvent` only accepts default events and I've found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72787150/playwright-wait-on-custom-events), but without any example.

Is there a reference in Playwright regarding validating on custom events?

Comment: Can you share some example code of what you mean? Why do you need custom events anyway? If you're triggering the event, you already know when it's triggered, right?

Answer (score 0):

yTo accomplish this, you'll probably have to lean on code that you evaluate inside the browser. I would do something like the following:

```js
const elementThatEmits = page.locator('#el');

// add listener for custom event
await elementThatEmits.evaluate((el) => {
  // evaluate runs code inside the browser
  el.addEventListener('custom-event', (e) => {
    window.EVENT_EMITTED = true;
  });
});

// await custom event
const res = await page.waitForFunction(() => {
  // executed in browser
  // will return when value is truth OR when timeout occurs
  return window.EVENT_EMITTED;
}, {timeout: 1000 * 60);

// `true` if successful
const val = await res.jsonValue();
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.